# How to check if element name contains the given string

Tags: javascript

In the code below I`m checking if these 2 elements exist.

```
const var1 = form.elements[elemName1] ||
          form.elements[elemName2]

if(var1){
  doSmth
}
```

But what I need is to check if element's name contains a certain string.
Like:

```
const var1 = form.elements[NameContains(givenString)] ||
          form.elements[NameContains(givenString)]
```

I tried to find the needed syntax in google bud did not succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [attribute contains selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings) (`*=`) with `querySelector` (to find the first) or `querySelectorAll` (to get a list of matches).

For instance:

```
const var1 = form.querySelector("[name*=foo]");
```

finds the first element in `form` whose `name` attribute contains the substring `foo`. Similarly there's `^=` for "starts with" and `$=` for "ends with."

If you're checking for two different substrings, either use a selector group:

```
const var1 = form.querySelector("[name*=foo], [name*=bar]");
```

or two calls:

```
const var1 = form.querySelector("[name*=foo]") || form.querySelector("[name*=bar]");
```

The difference between those is that the selector group will find the **first** matching element in document order, whether it's a `foo` or `bar` element. The second will look for a `foo` element first, and only look for a `bar` element if no `foo` is found.

Comment: Can I use it like this:
`
const var1 = form.querySelector(`[name*=${stringVar}]`)
`

Comment: @TirelessCoder - Sure. That template literal evaluates to a string, which is what `querySelector` expects. If `stringVar` might include anything that prevents it being a valid [CSS identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) (such as anything other than `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, `-`, and `_`), be sure to put it in quotes: ```form.querySelector(`[name*="${stringVar}"]`)```. (That assumes you know `stringVar` doesn't have a `"` in it. :-) )

Comment: @TirelessCoder - Glad that helped! BTW, if you ever want to have a backtick in code in a comment as you tried to above, you can do that by using three backticks around the code rather than just one. For instance, ```>`<``` is backtick backtick backtick > backtick < backtick backtick backtick. :-)